# how to assign values for list of students while doing group

Tags: c#, linq

I have a plain list of data like this,

```
List<SchoolData> schoolData = new List<SchoolData>
        {
            new SchoolData{ClassName = "A", StudentName = "abc", StudentAge = 1},
            new SchoolData{ClassName = "A", StudentName = "xyz", StudentAge = 2},
            new SchoolData{ClassName = "B", StudentName = "pqr", StudentAge = 10},
            new SchoolData{ClassName = "B", StudentName = "lmn", StudentAge = 11},
        };
```

Here I need to group data by `ClassName` and arrange data like this,

```
var d = new List<RedefineSchoolData>()
        {
            new RedefineSchoolData{ClassName = "A", Students = new List<Student>
            {
                new Student{StudentName = "abc", StudentAge = 1},
                new Student{StudentName = "xyz", StudentAge = 2}
            }}
        };
```

I am trying to do like this, but how to fill `Students`?

```
var group = schoolData.GroupBy(x => x.ClassName);

        foreach (var g in group)
        {
            redefineSchoolDatas.Add(new RedefineSchoolData
            {
                ClassName = g.Key,
                Students = g.ToList() //how to convert
            });
        }
```

Here all the class structure,

```
 public class SchoolData
    {
        public string ClassName { get; set; }
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public int StudentAge { get; set; }
    }

    public class RedefineSchoolData
    {
        public string ClassName { get; set; }
        public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }

    public class Student
    {
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public int StudentAge { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the following line to get the Student property:

```
Students = g.Select(s => new Student
{
    StudentName = s.StudentName,
    StudentAge = s.StudentAge
}).ToList()
```

You can also replace `foreach` with:

```
var redefineSchoolDatas = group.Select(g => new RedefineSchoolData
{
    ClassName = g.Key,
    Students = g.Select(s => new Student
    {
        StudentName = s.StudentName,
        StudentAge = s.StudentAge
    }).ToList(),
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do everything inside the GroupBy:

```
var newList = schoolData
    .GroupBy(
        x => x.ClassName,
        (k,v) => new RedefineSchoolData(){
            ClassName=k,
            Students=v.Select(s => new Student(){
                StudentName=s.StudentName,
                StudentAge=s.StudentAge
                }).ToList()
        })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Magnetron. very nice one liner :)